# How can I get an order "shipping method" from bigcommerce API (Ground, Express)?

Tags: bigcommerce

How can I get an order "shipping method" from bigcommerce API (Ground, Express)?

The shipping method that customer selects when placing an order.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Refer this [page](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/orders/shipping_addresses#get-order-shipping-address), to get shipping related data for particular order.