# Get shipping method for order using BigCommerce API

Tags: bigcommerce

Is there a way to get the shipping method for a specific order using the BigCommerce API? I've searched and the closest I came to finding an answer is this, [How can I get an order "shipping method" from bigcommerce API (Ground, Express)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25813782/how-can-i-get-an-order-shipping-method-from-bigcommerce-api-ground-express) , unfortunately the link provided is broken. I can't even find a 'shipping_id' in the order object that I can use to determine the method based on available shipping methods in the store.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the updated link for that https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/v2/#order-shipping-address-object-properties

Since you are looking for the Shipping methods for an Order it will be under the Order resource in the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

It's in the `shipping_method` field of the Shipment object:

[Shipment object](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/v2/#shipments)

You link back to the `order_id`on the Shipment object with the `id` from the Order object:

[Order object](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/v2/#order-object-properties)

Comment: Thanks for the information. Is there a way to access the Shipment object using the Python SDK for BigCommerce API? I've tried every combination of calls that I can think of and I'm having no luck and can't find any helpful documentation anywhere.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with the Python SDK (or Python in general).  But if you can call a RESTful service with it and process a JSON response, then the links I sent should do the trick for you.  If you post some sample code, I might be able to help further.